# Generic function to serialize from std::any

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, c++17

I am trying to create a function that serializes an object stored as `std::any`. The idea is, object is stored in std::any along with a function that can serialize it, then that function is called on the object.

I am running into the following problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, int (*F)(T& t)>
int _GetDataFromAny(std::any& input)
{
    return F(std::any_cast<T&>(input));
}

struct MyStruct
{
    int val = 69;  
};

int Fun(MyStruct& str) { return str.val; }

template<typename T>
void DoStuff(T& s, int (*F)(T&))
{
    auto an = make_any<T>(s);
    cout << _GetDataFromAny<MyStruct, F>(an);
}

int main()
{
    MyStruct s = {71};

    DoStuff(s, Fun);     /* does not compile */
    
    /* Works fine */
    auto an = make_any<MyStruct>(s);
    cout << _GetDataFromAny<MyStruct, Fun>(an);

    return 0;
}
```

There are 2 versions of this code, one that has the `DoStuff` line and one that doesn't. The idea behind `DoStuff` is that it can construct both the `std::any` container and an appropriate function to serialize that object, however I cannot compile `DoStuff` (however everything else does compile).

The exact error I get is:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void DoStuff(T&, int (*)(T&)) [with T = MyStruct]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',38)">main.cpp:38:19</span>:   required from here
main.cpp:31:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘_GetDataFromAny(std::any&)’
     cout << _GetDataFromAny<MyStruct, F>(an);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
main.cpp:15:5: note: candidate: template int _GetDataFromAny(std::any&)
 int _GetDataFromAny(std::any& input)
```

I am not entirely sure as to why template subsitituion is failing.

Comment: `F` is a function parameter, which is not a compile time constant. Template arguments are resolved at compilation so they must be compile time constants. You'd have to pass `F` as a template argument to `DoStuff`.

Comment: Heads up: `_GetDataFromAny` is a [reserved identifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) because it starts with an underscore followed by a capital. You should choose a different name.

Comment: @alterigel How can I indicate an internal function? Because these are templates they have to be on the header but I want to dissuade people from calling them directly.

Comment: @Makogan *"How can I indicate an internal function?"* Put them in your own `namespace`. A lot of projects include a `details` nested namespace for private implementation details that have to be exposed but that users should ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`F` as a function parameter can't be used as a template argument. It's not a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

`F` would have to be a template parameter in order for this code to compile. Function arguments are never constant expressions.